# SQL Server error: The conversion of char data type to smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range smalldatetime value

Tags: sql-server

I run into this error with my statement:

```
insert into messages ([from], [to], [message], Subject, status, senderID, 
                      PassengerID, Taxis, bags, passengers, dest, Comments, [when])
values(2, 81, '2', 'Bid', 1, 2, 
       2, 2, 2, 2, '2', '2', CONVERT(smalldatetime, '25.7.2016 13:01'))
```

I get this error:

> The conversion of char data type to smalldatetime data type resulted in an out-of-range smalldatetime value.

When running the same statement on the console, it works perfectly fine!

Comment: "When running the same statement on the console, it works perfect!!!" So where does it _not_ work? From a webapp? From a remote SSMS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an appropriate `style` parameter in [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx) function like this -

```
Insert into messages ([from],[to],[message],Subject,status,senderID,PassengerID,Taxis,bags,passengers, dest, Comments,[when])
   values(2,81,'2','Bid',1,2,2,2,2,2,'2','2',CONVERT(smalldatetime, '25.7.2016 13:01', 104))
```

Comment: Thank You, It works. But Why in the console it was perfect?

Comment: The regional settings on the console vs [unspecified other place where it didn't work] must be different, with different day/month ordering within dates.

Comment: @underscore_d: Yes, i agree with you.

Comment: Thank You very much

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with your server settings. Seems that your server waits for an US Date format (mm dd yyy) while you enter a european format (dd mm yyyy).